# dot-app wrapper for Windows programs

Tags: windows

Several months ago, I was interested in a Windows program "Azuon."  They had instructions on how to install it on Mac OS by getting a "wrapper" from somewhere else.  Sort of like WINE or CrossOver but it put everything needed inside the .app bundle.

I'd like to use the same technique for some other programs, but I can't remember the name of the thing.  I went back to Azuon's website to find out, but they have since done the packaging themselves and no longer cite the other site.

Where is this "embedded WINE" code, or what is its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only I had searched for fifteen minutes instead of ten....

It's "Wineskin" at http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php

Now to figure out how to use it....

Comment: According to the link in your answer, Wineskin (2.6.1+) works on 10.6 through and including OS X 10.11 El Capitan. Are you saying you tried it under OS X 10.11 El Capitan and it didn't work for you?

Comment: No, I saw several complaints before I actually saw their website.  I should have looked at it longer before posting.

Comment: Haven't got it to work yet.  Every attempt complains about failure to load a DLL.  Have to use a utility program to install the DLL, but it's not always obvious which option on the util is the one needed.  First time, I got it right, but then Mono had an unhanded exception.  Second time, loading a different DLL (and I'm certain it was the right one) still complained it couldn't open it.  Obviously Azuon got it to work, but ....